# What does "I find" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does this sentence mean?

> **I find** if I drink coffee too late at night, I can't sleep.

Is this wrong?

> If I drink coffee too late at night, I can't sleep.

Comment: Please specify which part of the phrase you are confused about, preferably in quotation marks (" "), as well as what confuses you about it.

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? It's a bit confusing.

Comment: It means: it happens that.

Comment: It means, "I have noticed (that)...". And yes, the second sentence is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct.

The verb "find" means (in this context) "have realised or discovered that something is true"

So the first means "I have discovered that [drinking coffee -> can't sleep]"

The second just states as a fact "drinking coffee -> can't sleep."

For another example, compare

> I can swim a mile.

> I found that I can swim a mile

The second sentence reports on the discovery.

You can put the word "that" after "find".  It might make it easier for you:

> I find that if I drink...

Comment: Okay,I understand.Thank you very much